# Arithmetic and Logic circuit Design

Tags: processor, alu

Suppose, we want to design an arithmetic and logic unit (ALU) so that it performs the following operations:
Say,
Two inputs are A and B. cin represents carry in.  s2,s1 and s0 are selection variables such that:

```
s2/cin   s1   s0   Function

0        0    0     Transfer A

0        0    1      Addition

1        0    0      A+1

1        0    1      Addition with carry

x        1    0      A OR B

x        1    1      A  XOR B
```

will the following circuit perform according to the above logic or any modification needed? The circuit has been designed for two stages.

Answer (score 0):

Dude!, write a verilog code and see RTL view, It gives clear idea whether it works or not, because you can see functional simulation too.